# Click menu item on Mac OSX Lion using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I have a problem using a simple AppleScript on Mac OSX 10.7.3.
With the following simple AppleScript which I find everywhere OSX raises an error 'The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error'

I open up the Automator, create a Service, drop in a "Run AppleScript" node and enter the following code which I assume is correct because as I said it is the way a lot of people are doing it without any complaints.

AppleScript:

> ```
> tell application "Terminal" to activate
>     tell application "System Events"
>         tell process "Terminal"
>             click menu item "New Window" of menu "Shell" of menu bar 1
>             tell application "Terminal" to close the front window
>         end tell
> end tell
> ```

EDIT: When running in Automator I also get an error description:

```
Run AppleScript failes -1 error
Access for assistive devices is disabled"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question but instead a "how to use" or "power user" question best asked on [su].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `Enable access for assistive devices` enabled? If so, have you tried to reenable it?

Comment: Alright. Seems to be a bug in the Mac OSX system.

In `System Preferences > Universal Access` the selection box `Enable access for assistive devices` was active what is right for my intention.
Now I deactivated it, ran the script again - error. Correct.
Then I reactivated, ran the script again - worked! Correct!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess I'll answer the question anyways (and thanks for editing your question to give a bit more useful detail).

Go to the "Universal Access" pane in System Preferences and at the bottom of the "Seeing" tab, you'll see a "Enable access for assistive devices" checkbox.

[image: Enable Assistive Devices]
Turn that on and I suspect Automator will work.